# Use APC with MAMP

Tags: php, mamp, fastcgi, apc

I've installed on my MAC MAMP 3.0.2 and I used PHP 5.4.25 .
This is my phpinfo:

[image]

I've already installed APC, and this is the APC page that MAMP show me:

[image]

I'm trying to run the follow php script:

```
<?php
$bar = 'BAR';
apc_store('foo', $bar);
var_dump(apc_fetch('foo'));
?>
```

but, when i run this script by command line I've the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function apc_store() in /Users/xxxxxxxxx/htdocs/prova.php on line 3
```

What's wrong?

--
Thanks

Comment: Did you install it separately or did you use the already-installed APC in MAMP?

Comment: I've tried with already-installed APC in MAMP and after I installed APC separately by pecl.

Comment: How are you calling it via the cli?

Comment: @cOle2 php <script.file.name>.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When running PHP scripts from the CLI you will need to specify the PHP binary you want to use since by default `php` will be the default PHP included with OS X, not the one installed with MAMP.

So instead of:

`user$ php script.php`

try:

`user$ /Applications/MAMP/bin/php script.php`

Obviously you will need to adjust the above with the path to where the MAMP PHP binary is located.